# How to understand reasoner ProgressMonitor output?

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl-api, reasoner

I'm new in the semantic web field and I'm trying to compare more reasoners. This is my code:

```
   OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
    Set<OWLClass> classes = ontology.getClassesInSignature();


    String inferredFile = args[1];
    //test for correctly uploading ontology
    OWLDataFactory df = manager.getOWLDataFactory();     
    Reasoner jfact = Reasoner.JFACT;
    System.out.println(RunReasoner(jfact, df,ontology,manager,inferredFile));



}

//CREATE AN ENUM REASONER
public enum Reasoner{
    HERMIT, 
    PELLET, 
    KONCLUDE,
    JFACT,
    FACT,
    ELK

}   
    public static String RunReasoner(Reasoner reasoner, OWLDataFactory df, OWLOntology ontology,                                                         OWLOntologyManager manager, String inferredFile) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, OWLOntologyStorageException {
    String esito = "";
    OWLReasoner reasoner_object = null;
    if(reasoner == Reasoner.HERMIT) {
        /****************HERMIT****************************************************************************************/

        OWLReasonerFactory rf = new ReasonerFactory();
        TimedConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new TimedConsoleProgressMonitor();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.reasonerProgressMonitor = progressMonitor;
        configuration.ignoreUnsupportedDatatypes = true;
        reasoner_object = rf.createReasoner(ontology, configuration);


    }
    else if(reasoner == Reasoner.KONCLUDE) {

        // configure the server end-point
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
        OWLlinkHTTPXMLReasonerFactory factory = new OWLlinkHTTPXMLReasonerFactory();
        TimedConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new TimedConsoleProgressMonitor();
        //OWLlinkReasonerConfiguration conf = (OWLlinkReasonerConfiguration) new SimpleConfiguration(progressMonitor);
        reasoner_object = factory.createNonBufferingReasoner(ontology);

    }
    else if(reasoner == Reasoner.JFACT) {
        TimedConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new TimedConsoleProgressMonitor();
        OWLReasonerConfiguration conf = new SimpleConfiguration(progressMonitor);
        JFactFactory factory = new JFactFactory();          
        reasoner_object = factory.createNonBufferingReasoner(ontology,conf);
    }
    //      else if(reasoner == Reasoner.FACT) {
    //          TimedConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new TimedConsoleProgressMonitor();
    //          OWLReasonerConfiguration conf = new SimpleConfiguration(progressMonitor);
    //          FaCTPlusPlusReasonerFactory factory = new FaCTPlusPlusReasonerFactory();
    //          reasoner_object = factory.createNonBufferingReasoner(ontology,conf);
    //      }
    else if(reasoner == Reasoner.ELK) {
        TimedConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new TimedConsoleProgressMonitor();
        OWLReasonerConfiguration conf = new SimpleConfiguration(progressMonitor);
        ElkReasonerFactory factory = new ElkReasonerFactory();
        reasoner_object = factory.createNonBufferingReasoner(ontology,conf);
    }
    else if(reasoner == Reasoner.PELLET) {
        TimedConsoleProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new TimedConsoleProgressMonitor();
        OWLReasonerConfiguration conf = new SimpleConfiguration(progressMonitor);
        reasoner_object = OpenlletReasonerFactory.getInstance().createReasoner(ontology,conf);          
    }
    else{
        esito = "Reasoner non valido";
    }
     boolean consistencyCheck = reasoner_object.isConsistent();
            if (consistencyCheck) {
                reasoner_object.precomputeInferences(InferenceType.CLASS_HIERARCHY,
                    InferenceType.CLASS_ASSERTIONS, InferenceType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_HIERARCHY,
                    InferenceType.DATA_PROPERTY_HIERARCHY, InferenceType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_ASSERTIONS);
                List<InferredAxiomGenerator<? extends OWLAxiom>> generators = new ArrayList<>();
                generators.add(new InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredClassAssertionAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredDataPropertyCharacteristicAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredEquivalentClassAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredEquivalentDataPropertiesAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredEquivalentObjectPropertyAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredInverseObjectPropertiesAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredObjectPropertyCharacteristicAxiomGenerator());

                // NOTE: InferredPropertyAssertionGenerator significantly slows down
                // inference computation
                generators.add(new org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.InferredPropertyAssertionGenerator());

                generators.add(new InferredSubClassAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredSubDataPropertyAxiomGenerator());
                generators.add(new InferredSubObjectPropertyAxiomGenerator());
                List<InferredIndividualAxiomGenerator<? extends OWLIndividualAxiom>> individualAxioms =
                    new ArrayList<>();
                generators.addAll(individualAxioms);

                generators.add(new InferredDisjointClassesAxiomGenerator());
                InferredOntologyGenerator iog = new InferredOntologyGenerator(reasoner_object, generators); //Generates an ontology based on inferred axioms which are essentially supplied by a reasoner

                OWLOntology inferredAxiomsOntology = manager.createOntology();
                iog.fillOntology(df, inferredAxiomsOntology);
                System.out.println(inferredAxiomsOntology.getAxiomCount());
    //                  for(InferredAxiomGenerator<?> i : iog.getAxiomGenerators()) {
    //                      System.out.println(i);}
                File inferredOntologyFile = new File(inferredFile);
                // Now we create a stream since the ontology manager can then write to that stream.
                try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(inferredOntologyFile)) {
                    // We use the same format as for the input ontology.
                    manager.saveOntology(inferredAxiomsOntology, outputStream);
                }
                esito = "done "+ reasoner.toString();
                reasoner_object.dispose();
            } // End if consistencyCheck
            else {
                esito = reasoner.toString() +" -- Inconsistent input Ontology, Please check the OWL File";
            }
    return esito;
}
```

my output is like:

```
Loading ...
    busy ...
    ... finished in 3484.5453
Classifying ...
    1%  73
    2%  56...
```

Someone can explain me what this means? is there some documentations about progress monitor output?
Second Question: how can I get the number of inferred class/axioms? 
Thanks for your help,
Rita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc for the class is available online and as part of the class source code http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/TimedConsoleProgressMonitor.html

The percentage increment is up to the reasoner implementation (and there might be unreliability there, in that the reasoner takes only an educated guess as to the amount of work done versus the amount of work still to do. The number is the milliseconds elapsed since the previous percentage increment.

The inferred axioms are not all computed, they're lazily evaluated when required, so they cannot be counted easily. If you wish to materialise inferences, look for InferredAxiomGenerator http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/index.html?org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/package-summary.html for the possibilities available.